# Get Author name from composite class Book

Tags: java, composite, composite-component

So, I'm new with Object-oriented programming. I have written a code to connect the composite and component class, I need to include at least one method that allows the composite class to communicate with the component class in order to compute some value. But my `Book` class is not showing the author's name.

This is my code:

```
public class Author{

private String name;
private String yearOfBirth;  

    public Author ()
    this.name = null;
    this.yearOfBirth = null;   
    }

    public Author (String aName)
    {
       this.name = aName;
       this.yearOfBirth = null;

   }
    public Author(String aName, String     aYear)
    {
  this.name = aName;
  this.yearOfBirth = aYear;
  }

public void setName(String aName)
  {
  this.name = aName;
 }

 public void setYearOfBirth(String aYear)
  {
  this.yearOfBirth = aYear;
 }

    public String getName()
    {
     return this.name;
     }

    public String getYearOfBirth()
     {
      return this.yearOfBirth;
    }  

public String toString()
{
   return this.name + "(Born " + this.yearOfBirth + ")";
}
```

**BOOK CLASS**

```
public class Book
{

 private String title;
 private String yearPublished;
 private Author author;


 public Book(String aTitle, String aYear,Author theAuthor)
  {
    this.title = aTitle;
    this.yearPublished = aYear;
    this.author = theAuthor;
   }


 public Book(String aTitle)
 {
   this.title = aTitle;
   this.yearPublished = null;
   this.author = new Author();
 }

 public void setAuthorName(String aName)
  {
      this.author.setName(aName);
 } 

  public void setYearPublished(String aYear)
  {
     this.yearPublished = aYear;
    }

     public String getTitle()
  {
     return this.title;   
  }

  public String getYearPublished()
   {
    if (this.yearPublished == null)
    {
       return "Unknown";
     }

     return this.yearPublished;
      }

   public String getAuthorName()
   {
     return this.author.getName();
    }

    public boolean isBorn()
    {
         return(Integer.parseInt
   (this.author.getYearOfBirth()) < 1900);
  }

public String toString()
  {

 {
    return "Title: " + this.title + ", Author: " + this.author.getName() + ", yearPublished: " + this.yearPublished+ ".";          
 }
```

So when I try and get the author name by doing something like: `Book hp = new Book ("Harry Potter","JK Rowling","2000");` it says in the display pane

```
Compilation failed (20/01/2020 15:02:12)
Error: line 1 - no suitable constructor found for Book(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
```

As you can see, the program does not print the name of the author.

I appreciate all the help!

Comment: This is unrelated to your `getAuthorName` method - you are calling the `Book` constructor with the wrong arguments, as the error message shows.

Comment: Please don't remove important information from your question. It's not here just for you, but also for future readers. If you remove the code, they will have no context about what's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your builder's call is no good.

Book class is waiting to get
a title like String ,
 one year of String type

and an Author type author

Example `Book book =new Book("test", "2020", new Author("MyAuthor"));`

Comment: the only problem is, when I inspect it.. the value for author is "inspect object" instead of the name of the author. Value for title is correct "Harry Potter" and yearPublished "2020"

Comment: May I ask how you inspect your code?
"inspect object" means it's an object, not just a value. You can call your toString() method to get the details. Example : Book book =new Book("test", "2020", new Author("MyAuthor")); System.out.println(book.toString());

Answer (score 0):

The third parameter which is accepted by the constructor of book is an object of author.

So the invocation should be like

Book hp = new Book ("Harry Potter",2000,new Author("JK Rowling",1965));

Comment: Also how would I test my isBorn method? as doing the following says cannot find method   jkr.isBorn();

Answer (score 0):

As the error message is telling you, you didn't define a constructor for `Book` that accepts three strings, as you are trying to call it in

```
Book hp = new Book ("Harry Potter","JK Rowling","2000");
```

(As a side note, you have author and year backwards)

You have two choices here.

First, you can create the author *before* calling the `Book` constructor

```
Author jkr = new Author("JK Rowling");
Book hp = new Book("Harry Potter", jkr, "2000");
```

Or you can create a new constructor inside `Book` that expects the name of the author as a string, builds the author object itself and then calls sets it as the author of the new book

```
public Book(String title, String author, String year) {
    this.title = title;
    this.author = new Author(author);
    this.yearPublished = year;
}
```

The first version has the advantage that you can fully utilize your `Author` class, for example to set the birth year of the author

```
Author jkr = new Author("JK Rowling", "1965");
Book hp = new Book("Harry Potter", jkr, "2000");
```

which the second version doesn't allow you to do without creating another constructor which accepts title, author's name, author's birth year, book publication year.

Comment: so this works Book hp =new Book("Harry Potter", "2020", new Author("JK Rowling")); but when i inspect it the author value is "inspect object" instead of the Authors name. When I double click on that, it does show the authors name and DOB

Comment: That's how it should be. `Author` is a class, and `author` inside your book is an instance of that class, so it can't be just a string. You have to inspect the object and see its fields' values. If what I just said is unclear, I suspect you should take a step back and re-read the part of whatever book/tutorial you used to learn this.

Comment: then its fine. Thank you for your help. it was so simple! and I was struggling. Also how would I test my isBorn method? as doing the following says cannot find method jkr.isBorn();

Comment: `isBorn` is part of `Book`, not of author, which doesn't make much sense, if you ask me. Move it inside `Author` (and modify `this.author.getYearOfBirth()` into `this.getYearOfBirth`). Note that that method, as it is now, only checks whether the author was born before 1900. I don't know how much that's useful to you, but still.

Comment: On a related note, both `Book::yearPublished` and `Author::birthDate` should probably be `int`s, not strings. And of course you'll have to update the method signatures for their getters, setters and for the constructors.

Comment: When I check the DOB of the author from within the hp variable and inspect object... it shows null as year of birth but in the jkr variable it shows the yearofbirth as 1965 instead of null. Why is it showing null through hp

Comment: With what code? We're making a mess, you should open another question, as the problem you were originally asking about has been thoroughly solved. Open another question, show the actual code you're using now and describe the problem you're now facing.